# System.InvalidCastException error in EF Core (usdig Raw Sql) when query returns no rows (but working when query returns rows)

Tags: mysql, sql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, pomelo-entityframeworkcore-mysql

In a .Net 5 Web Api application, I am reading some rows from a MySql table (using the Pomelo library).
I am using a raw sql query. So:

```
MySqlParameter propertyIdParam = new MySqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@propertyId",
    MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32,
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
    Value = 7
};

List<PropertyRepairsDto> propertyRepairs = await _context.PropertyRepairs
    .FromSqlRaw("some sql query", propertyIdParam)
    .AsNoTracking()
    .ToListAsync();
```

The strange thing is that this works well, until I provide a parameter ("propertyId") which doesn't exist - so that the query returns no rows. In that case, I get the following exception:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/Core/Row.cs:line 211
   at MySqlConnector.MySqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal) in /_/src/MySqlConnector/MySqlDataReader.cs:line 238
   at lambda_method848(Closure , QueryContext , DbDataReader , Int32[] )
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.FromSqlQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at PropWorx.API.Controllers.PropertiesController.GetPropertyRepairsAsync(Int32 id) in C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\Controllers\PropertiesController.cs:line 194
   at lambda_method479(Closure , Object )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at PropWorx.API.Middlewares.TenantIdentifier.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, SharedContext sharedContext) in C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\Middlewares\TenantIdentifier.cs:line 52
   at PropWorx.API.Middlewares.WebSocketsMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext) in C:\Users\fabsr\source\repos\PropWorx.API\PropWorx.API\Middlewares\WebSocketsMiddleware.cs:line 28
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler.HandleAsync(RequestDelegate next, HttpContext context, AuthorizationPolicy policy, PolicyAuthorizationResult authorizeResult)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Session.SessionMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

HEADERS
=======
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCIsImtpZCI6Ik1ERXpSRUUwUWpFMk9VTkdOa0kyUlRJMFJEUXdNakExUTBFeE1EUkNRalpDUmtWR1JVTXhOQSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2NvZGV4Y3JlYXRpb25zLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw1OTI2YjEwYTAxZTkxZDE0MGU5OWVlNjQiLCJhdWQiOlsiaHR0cHM6Ly9wcm9wd29yeC5jby56YS9hcGkiLCJodHRwczovL2NvZGV4Y3JlYXRpb25zLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS91c2VyaW5mbyJdLCJpYXQiOjE2MTAwMDkyMjQsImV4cCI6MTYxMjYwMTIyNCwiYXpwIjoiUnppNzVkU1dpcVlFYlJsVjU1N0lFd1dQYUI5Qmwzd3giLCJzY29wZSI6Im9wZW5pZCBwcm9maWxlIGVtYWlsIn0.WK2gtsbWtiz1WIkJrO56Ap8fqyyyLBs1wiKcs0KvTVTPKlzVyicf6J9S-9PMDGs1uT-gho7fVW6gLVv9XzLCulcR4x3KFrNmLSW9lvsj9fyKPMQ4Udp4A2UdfYoogRXduB62QwqRhkYGbNkI-tSGgMwF-zgClirKalpY6oKs9yMY6qr_XC4ZzTI27Pd4W9wverLtLT0-1WNlh4ynUF_xE5uvfKfh0KhBITs-KASUBMz7WcloSehNqvnkwOOdLCcWtkcbcms4LRklwEzpQvXiuCwAgjpjq980fjFjYSISjD5paqBM_rdpvG4Yz4OqI6FXtccuszbc_1WcXe7O_CSuTg
Host: localhost:5001
Referer: http://localhost:5000/api/properties/6823/repairs
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Content-Length: 2856
clientId: 273
Postman-Token: fe2fcc49-3f1b-451b-8e06-b808fa28964c
```

I don't understand how it's possible that it works fine when the query returns rows (so it's mapping the database data correctly to the model fields), but when the query returns no rows (which I would assume should simply result in a List of zero items) it throws an exception.

The exception suggests a problem converting a value from the database to int32. At first, I thought it might be a null that's trying to be mapped to a non-nullable integer in my model, but ALL integer fields in my model are nullable. But even so, since the query is not returning any rows, surely it shouldnt even be a problem as there is nothing to map?

I know it's difficult to assist me without seeing the database structures, models, queries, etc. It's just that the query and tables are quite big, and I thought perhaps someone has experienced this problem before, where things work until a query is called which returns no rows, in which case a System.InvalidCastException is thrown.

Here is the model I am mapping to, for what it's worth:

```
public class PropertyRepairsDto
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public int? FileId { get; set; }
    public string FileNum { get; set; }
    public bool? IsRequired { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public bool? QuotesObtained { get; set; }
    public decimal? QuoteAmount { get; set; }
    public string ContractorAppointed { get; set; }
    public bool? IsPaid { get; set; }
    public decimal? AmountPaid { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobDate { get; set; }
    public bool? PaymentRequired { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PaymentDate { get; set; }
    public string PaymentReference { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportedAt { get; set; }
    public int? ContractorId { get; set; }
    public string Contractor { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFixedByOwner { get; set; }
    public DateTime? FollowUpDate { get; set; }
    public string WorkOrderNumber { get; set; }
    public bool? IsCompleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CompletedDate { get; set; }
    public bool? IsInvoiceReceived { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InvoiceReceivedAt { get; set; }
    public decimal? InvoiceAmount { get; set; }
    public bool? IsInvoiceApproved { get; set; }
    public DateTime? InvoiceApprovedAt { get; set; }
    public string InvoiceApprovedBy { get; set; }
    public bool? ChargeToTenant { get; set; }
    public bool? IsReportedToOwner { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportedToOwnerAt { get; set; }
    public int? InvoiceDocId { get; set; }
    public int? ReportedById { get; set; }
    public string ReportedBy { get; set; }
    public int? PriorityId { get; set; }
    public string Priority { get; set; }
    public int? QuotesRequired { get; set; }
    public bool? InvoiceOwner { get; set; }
    public bool? InvoiceTenant { get; set; }
    public bool? IsReportSentToTenant { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReportSentToTenantAt { get; set; }
    public bool? IsJobCardSentToServiceProvider { get; set; }
    public int? JobCardSentToId { get; set; }
    public string JobCardSentTo { get; set; }
    public int? JobCardSentToServiceProviderById { get; set; }
    public string JobCardSentToServiceProviderBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? JobCardSentToServiceProviderAt { get; set; }

    public int? StatusId { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public int? PropertyId { get; set; }
    public int? AssignedToId { get; set; }
    public string AssignedTo { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public DateTime? AddedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: My advise is to examine generated query.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks for the reply. I’m actually supplying the sql query. I’m using the FromSqlRaw method and supplying it the query. And the query works. I’ve tested it directly on MySQL Workbench. But also the exact same query works when I give it a record which exists (I.e. the parameter in the WHERE clause of the query actually exists and so the query returns records). When the parameter in the WHERE clause refers to a record which doesn’t exist, and therefore no records are returned, I get the “The specified cast is not valid” exception.

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez Sorry, missed this one because you put it under the wrong tag. We need the exact LINQ query (including the exact SQL query you use in your `FromSqlRaw()` call) for further analysis. You would also need to tell us, what exact version of Pomelo (and MySqlConnector) you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to replicate this behavior. I updated and used the following sample code, that includes the `GROUP_CONCAT` aggregate function that you mentioned in your comment, which works without issues in Pomelo `5.0.0-alpha.2`:

```cs
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using MySqlConnector;
using Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql.Infrastructure;

namespace IssueConsoleTemplate
{
    public class IceCream
    {
        public int IceCreamId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
    }
    
    public class Context : DbContext
    {
        public virtual DbSet<IceCream> IceCreams { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var connectionString = "server=127.0.0.1;port=3306;user=root;password=;database=So65847111_GroupConcat";
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(
                    connectionString,
                    ServerVersion.AutoDetect(connectionString),
                    options => options.CharSetBehavior(CharSetBehavior.NeverAppend))
                .UseLoggerFactory(
                    LoggerFactory.Create(
                        configure => configure
                            .AddConsole()
                            .AddFilter(level => level >= LogLevel.Information)))
                .EnableSensitiveDataLogging()
                .EnableDetailedErrors();
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<IceCream>(
                entity =>
                {
                    entity.Property(e => e.Name)
                        .HasDefaultValue("Vanilla");
                    
                    entity.HasData(
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 1, Name = "Vanilla", Company = "Icecold"},
                        new IceCream {IceCreamId = 2, Name = "Chocolate", Company = "Mr IceCream"});
                });
        }
    }

    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var context = new Context();
            
            context.Database.EnsureDeleted();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();
            
            var iceCreamIdParameter = new MySqlParameter
            {
                ParameterName = "@iceCreamIdParam",
                MySqlDbType = MySqlDbType.Int32,
                Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input,
                Value = 42, // <-- does not exist
            };

            var iceCreams = context.IceCreams
                .FromSqlRaw(@"
SELECT `IceCreamId`, `Name`, `Company`, GROUP_CONCAT(`Name`, `Company` SEPARATOR ', ') AS `FullName`
FROM `IceCreams`
WHERE `IceCreamId` = @iceCreamIdParam
GROUP BY `IceCreamId`, `Name`, `Company`", iceCreamIdParameter)
                .AsNoTracking()
                .ToList();

            Trace.Assert(iceCreams.Count == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

So to help you, we need more information:

- The the exact LINQ query (including the exact SQL query you use in your FromSqlRaw() call)
- The database server type (e.g. `MySQL` or `MariaDB`) and its exact version (e.g. `8.0.21`)

(Just update the OP with the requested information.)

---

The exception hints, that one of your returned fields does not contain the type (or nullability) that it should:

> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
> at MySqlConnector.Core.Row.GetInt32(Int32 ordinal)

So your query expects an `Int32`, but the returned value is something else.
Let your debugger break when the exception is thrown in `Row.GetInt32()` and examine the value it tries to cast to `Int32`. Then examine the `ordinal` parameter of the method. Finally, check the expression at the same position as the `ordinal` parameter in the SQL query that EF Core generated (you should find it in the `Command.CommandText` property of the `MySqlDataReader` object in the stack, or you can just log it with EF Core).

---

In addition to that, you can run the code I posted on your server. It should work flawlessly. If it doesn't, than this should be related to some unexpected MySQL server setting.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and work you did lauxjpn. I traced the exception to this bit of SQL code. Specifically, the problem seems to be the fact that I'm using a GROUP_CONCAT. If  I replace it with a regular CONCAT, then it works. It seems that either RF Core 5 or POMELO have a problem with GROUP_CONCAT when no rows are returned, at least in specific circumstances, as I used GROUP_CONCAT plenty and never experienced this issue before. But then again, I recently upgraded to .Net 5 so it could be a new bug in .Net 5 or the corresponding Pomelo v5.0.0-alpha.2

Comment: So the offending SQL code is "GROUP_CONCAT(`person`.`name`, `person`.`surname`, SEPARATOR ',')" - if I replace GROUP_CONCAT with a regular CONCAT, or if I remove this line altogether, then it works

Comment: But I should reiterate, I only get an exception when the query returns no rows. If at least one row is returned, everything works fine. And this only happens in my .Net 5 project - if I run the exact same query in MySql Workbench, for example, everything works fine, regardless of wether rows are returned or not

Comment: @FabricioRodriguez I updated my answer with new code that runs fine as well. I added a bit of analysis after the code.